# How to save all the exceptions in database without calling the function everywhere in project in .Net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I want to save all the exceptions log in the database in .NET. It is very time consuming to insert exception into database in every try catch block. Is there any possible generic permanent solution? Is there any service which runs at every exception throw by the try/catch black, so that I modify that service and insert  every exception in database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try putting some logic in the `Application_Error` event of `Global.asax` in your project files. That will execute everytime an unhandled error occurs.

Something like this would help :

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

  // Get the exception object.
  Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

  //handle your exception here.
}
```

Also, since its your requirement its fine, otherwise its not a bad idea to write different exception code blocks for different functions since you might want to handle some exceptions in a different way than the others.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. This is the answer i am looking for. Well done pal :) Thanks.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Would appreciate if you can mark it as answer for future readers as well. :)

Comment: Requires 15 reputation to up your answer friend. I am a newbie. As i get the reputation required i'l sure mark your answer :)

Comment: @waleedansari - Appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can save all the exceptions  in the database using ELMAH OR log4net

Here is the link:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs

I hope it will solve your Problem..

Comment: Isn't there any builtin support provided by the .Net ?? as i don't wanna use any external lib.